# Prevent hover over active state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

How to prevent hovering button,div,li if it already has active status by means of css?

```
#list-of-tests .item-test:hover {
    background-color: #4d5f75;
    border: solid 1px #4d5f75;
}

#list-of-tests .item-test:active {
    background-color: #93c3cd;
    border: solid 1px #93c3cd;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways:

1) Use `!important` for the `:active` state:

```
#list-of-tests .item-test:active {
    background-color: #93c3cd !important;
    border: solid 1px #93c3cd !important;
}
```

2) Specify multiple states:

```
#list-of-tests .item-test:active,
#list-of-tests .item-test:active:hover {
    background-color: #93c3cd;
    border: solid 1px #93c3cd;
}
```